# Java - Looping over complex collection of Objects

Tags: java, loops, arraylist, collections, linkedhashmap

I have a general question about looping over a collection containing a complex object.

- I have a `Collection<Object>`, which contains an `Array<E>` of `LinkedHashMap<K,V>` that I'm trying to extract values from.
- I have tried various loops to get to the Key, Value pair but with no luck, something like;

The object looks like;

[image: Complex Object]

```java
Collection<Object> dsidsToExclude = Arrays.asList(param.get("idsToExclude"));
    for(Object id : dsidsToExclude) {
            if(id instanceof ArrayList) {
            // Loop over the list of <K,V>
            for(Object kv : id) {
               // I want to get extract the kv pairs here..
              }
            }
        }
```

I want to know what the best way of doing this efficiently, any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As long as the contents of the input collection may be specified as `Collection<List<Map<K, V>>>` (note use of interfaces `List` and `Map` instead of implementations `ArrayList` and `LinkedHashMap`), it would be more appropriate to implement a generic method typed with `K, V` to get rid of `instanceof` and explicit casting:

```java
public static <K, V> doSomething(Collection<List<Map<K, V>>> input) {
    for (List<Map<K, V>> list : input) {
        for (Map<K, V> map : list) {
            for (Map.Entry<K, V> entry : map.entrySet()) {
                // do what is needed with entry.getKey() , entry.getValue()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

Similarly, methods `forEach` may be used for the collection, list, and map:

```java
public static <K, V> doSomethingForEach(Collection<List<Map<K, V>>> input) {
    input.forEach(list ->
        list.forEach(map ->
            map.forEach((k, v) -> // do what is needed with key k and value v
                System.out.printf("key: %s -> value: %s%n", k, v);
            );
        )
    );
}
```

---

Also, it is possible to use Stream API, particularly `flatMap` to access contents of all innermost maps. Optionally, `null` values may be filtered as shown below

```java
public static <K, V> doSomethingStream(Collection<List<Map<K, V>>> input) {
    input.stream()                 // Stream<List<Map<K, V>>>
         .filter(Objects::nonNull) // discard null entries in collection
         .flatMap(List::stream)    // Stream<Map<K, V>>
         .filter(Objects::nonNull) // discard null entries in list
         .flatMap(map -> map.entrySet().stream()) // Stream<Map.Entry<K, V>>
         .forEach(e -> System.out.printf(
             "key: %s -> value: %s%n", e.getKey(), e.getValue()
         ));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Arrays.asList(something)` will generate list with one element. You do not need to do it.

```
Object object = param.get("idsToExclude");
```

You can check object and cast to list.

```
if (object instanceof List) {
  List list = (List) object;
}
```

Every item in the list needs to be checked and cast.

```
for (Object item : list) {
  if (item instanceof Map) {
    Map map = (Map) item;
  }
}
```

You can get key and value from map item.

```
Object key = map.getKey();
Object value = map.getValue();
```

Full example:

```
Object object = param.get("idsToExclude");
if (object instanceof List) {
  List list = (List) object;
  for (Object item : list) {
    if (item instanceof Map) {
      Map map = (Map) item;
      Object key = map.getKey();
      Object value = map.getValue();
      // You can cast key and value to other object if you need it
    }
  }
}
```